# Wanted to modify some port in xml file file using "Read/Modify xml file" Action Command

Tags: xml, installanywhere

I am using InstallAnywhere_2011_SP4 and wanted to modify XML file using "Read/Modify xml file" Action Command.enter code here

below is the XML file which i wanted to modify port number 8080 to some other 4digit number using read/modify xml file action command.

I have tried using multiple Read/Modify XML File actions what is there in installAnywhere 2011 Help Library but it is modifying first occurrence of  tag(modify @ 3rd line). But i wanted to modify @10th line

Can anyone please help me out.

```
1.<Configure id=....................................>
2.<New id="YYYY" class="XXXXX">
3.<Set name="AAAA"><Property name="BBBB" default="." />/XX/yy.com</Set>
4.<Set name="CCCCC">khgsjkhdfjjlskdfjlks</Set>
5.</New>
6.<Call name="DDDDD">
7.<Arg>
8.<New class="FF.GG.COM">
9.<Arg><Ref id="HHHH" /></Arg>
10.<Set name="Port">8080</Set>
11.<Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
12.<Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
13.<Set name="AcceptQueueSize">100</Set>
14.</New>
15.</Arg>
16.</Call>
17.</Configure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat the XML file as a simple text file and use the "Modify Text File - Single File" Action to search for and replace your port number.

First, create a variable (say, `$INSTALL_PORT_NUMBER$`). Be sure to set it with your new port number before this step executes.

Add the "Modify Text File - Single File" Action to the appropriate location in your project.

Configure the settings as needed. You should probably uncheck "*Substitute InstallAnywhere variables in file*".

Click "*Configure...*" and add a row. In the new row, set the "*Search For*" value to

`<Set name="Port">8080</Set>`

(the same as in your example, above).

Set the "*Replace With*" value to

`<Set name="Port">$INSTALL_PORT_NUMBER$</Set>`

When this step executes, assuming the selected file is present, the "*Search For*" value will be found and replaced with the "*Replace With*" value. For instance, if `$INSTALL_PORT_NUMBER$` holds the value of `8888`, then the port setting line will become:

`<Set name="Port">8888</Set>`